# Entity Framework 4.1 data real time

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, real-time

I'm using EF version 4.1, and would like to have the data from the database in realtime, i.e. if you open the application it detects if there is new data in the database, and update the above it! is It possible to do this?

I am using EF 4.1 code first time

Cumps

Comment: you will get better help if you post some code you tried @daniel

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't a way to do this with EF but you could setup a timer to kick off every say 30 seconds or so and check the database for new data.

Comment: My idea is work in bk work with timer, but there will be way to compare the contexts, and examine which are the new record?